# How to Make Parent-Child-Parent scope stay inside of Parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the models Dad, Mom and Kid. I have a boolean attribute on my Mom called `is_online`. Now I'm doing a pagination chain like this:

```
def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
  @kids =  @dad.kids.online.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Allowing me to see a list of the Dad's kids who's moms are online only.

My models are setup like this:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dad
  belongs_to :mom

  scope :online, joins(:mom).where("moms.is_online = ?", true)
end

class Dad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end

class Mom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end
```

The problem I'm having is this doesn't return just this Dad's kids with online moms but instead returns ALL Dad's. How can I get the scope to be correct?

**EDIT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT "kids"."dad_id" FROM "kids"
 => [14, 25, 27, 8, 12, 17, 28, 1, 15, 10, 26, 11, 4, 18, 30, 16, 6, 19, 29, 2, 21, 3, 23, 31, 20, 5, 13, 22, 9, 7, 24]

Kid Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "kids".* FROM "kids" INNER JOIN "moms" ON "moms"."id" = "kids"."mom_id" WHERE (moms.is_online = 't')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
 #<Kid id: 7, dad_id: 1, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 21, dad_id: 2, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 35, dad_id: 3, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 49, dad_id: 4, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 63, dad_id: 5, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 77, dad_id: 6, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 91, dad_id: 7, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 105, dad_id: 8, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 119, dad_id: 9, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, 
 #<Kid id: 133, dad_id: 10, mom_id: 5, created_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48", updated_at: "2014-04-28 16:10:48">, ...]>
```

Comment: Go on the `rails console` and fire `@dad.kids.online` for a `dad` and share the SQL query generated. Add it in the question

Comment: Also, if possible, share the output of `Kid.all.distinct.pluck(:dad_id)`. This way we will know if all the kids belong to only `@dad.id` or you have kids records for different dads.

Comment: When you say "returns ALL Dad's" do you mean "returns the kids of ALL Dads"?

Comment: @MaxWilliams That's my question too. Also, OP's original setup should work as it is without any problem, I just tried exact scenario and it works. What do you think? I wish OP shares output of `Kid.all.distinct.pluck(:dad_id)`.

Comment: Yeah, looking at it, i'd expect it to work too.  Perhaps it's doing it's job correctly and he's made some assumptions about his data which are not correct.  Eg, maybe every dad DOES have a kid who's mom is online.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yeah. For some strange reason it wasn't just returning the Dad that I'm trying to find (dad/id/show) but all the kids and dads. For ex. if I had 3 dads and 3 kids with 3 online moms. It would return all 3 kids and all 3 dads.

Comment: Are you sure you have different dads for different kids and not the same dad (`@dad.id`) for all the kids? I would really appreciate if you could share the output of `Kid.all.distinct.pluck(:dad_id)` from `rails console`.

Comment: @user2784630 Thanks for sharing. :) It is strange. Is it possible for you to share the output of `@dad.kids.online` as well from `rails console` for the same `@dad` you tried viewing.

Comment: @KirtiThorat How would I do that? Keep in mind, I'm new to rails.

Comment: You must have got more than that one sql query - i'd expect it to do a join or to split it into two simpler queries.  It looks like it's done the latter and you've just included one of them.

Comment: @user2784630 On `rails console`, just type `@dad=Dad.find(pass_an_existing_id)` and after that next command as `@dad.kids.online` and share the results for these two commands.

Comment: @user2784630 Thanks. And what was the query generated for `@dad.kids.online`. Could you share that as well.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Oh yeah, forgot. Take a look now.

Comment: @user2784630 If you got a moment then let's debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `scope` as below:

```
scope :online, -> { joins(:mom).where("moms.is_online = ?", true) }
```

Somehow, in `Rails 4` your scope `online` is not getting chained to the query formed with `@dad.kids`. Above is the correct way to define a **[Scope in Rails 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)**

Comment: **@KirtiThorat** I just answered this elsewhere lol! It turns out that in Rails 4, all scopes must be *callable* objects (i.e. lambdas or Procs). Simply shifting the `scope :online` definition into a lambda as you've done will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

As mentioned by **@KirtiThorat**, the *real* reason that the OP's scope method wasn't working is due to a change in ActiveRecord scope definitions with the release of Rails 4. Specifically, according the [upgrading Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record):

> Rails 4.0 requires that scopes use a callable object such as a Proc or lambda

With that in mind, simply redefining the `:online` scope definition within a lambda should fix the problem:

```
scope :online, -> {joins(:mom).where("mom.is_online = ?", true)}
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Your best bet is to use the `merge` method:

```
def show
 @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
 @kids = @dad.kids.merge(Kid.online)
end
```

As the ActiveRecord docs define `merge`:

> **merge**(`other`) *public*
>   Merges in the conditions from `other`, if `other` is an ActiveRecord::Relation. Returns an array representing the *intersection* of the resulting records with `other`, if `other` is an array.

As such, since `merge` finds the intersection of the two arrays, in this case, the array of `@dad`'s kids and `Kid`s with online `Mom`s, this will yield the array containing all `Kid`s with `@dad` as their `Dad` and a `Mom` who `is_online`.

It is also nice to know that the array intersection shorthand method `&` can be used too:

```
def show
 @dad = Dad.find(params[:dad_id])
 @kids = @dad.kids & Kid.online
end
```

Comment: I am just curious to know, what was the issue with OP's original setup. I just tried exact scenario and it works without any issue. Again, nothing wrong with your answer. I just want to challenge myself why it didn't work on the first base.

Comment: **@KirtiThorat** Honestly, as you've mentioned in the OP's comments, it is difficult to tell why his original query wasn't working without having access to his db schema and entries. It seems to me that the entire query could be written in any number of ways, including the way the OP had it set up, but I can't be certain without seeing his/her db.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it will work on not, but you can try following approach::

```
class Dad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
  has_many :kids_with_online_mom, class_name: `Kid`, through: :mom,  joins(:mom).where("moms.is_online = ?", true)
end
```

if it works, just by `@dad.kids_with_online_mom`, you will get desired output.